# How to infer a function's parameter type from its return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function like the following:

```
function create<T>(fn: (get: () => T) => T): typeof fn {
  // ...
  return fn;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
create((get) => ({
  x: 5,
  f() {
    console.log(get().x);
  }
}));
```

I expect `5` to get logged.

However, TypeScript fails to compile `get()` with "Object is of type 'unknown'". Is there a way to type this function **without** having to redundantly write `create<{ x: number }>((get) => ({ ...` or having to make `create` take more than one argument?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that the kind of self-dependent type you've got here can be inferred by the compiler.  See [ms/TS#38872](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for an example of this kind of issue.  TypeScript does not have a full unification algorithm for type inference; it uses a set of heuristics.  It will see that your callback is context-dependent (because you haven't annotated `get`) and make a first pass that plugs in something like `any` for what it doesn't know in order to try to infer `T`. But then there's nothing to infer from, so it falls back to `unknown`.

Comment: The only way to cut this knot in TS as it is now is to give TS some concrete type annotation somewhere you are currently hoping it will infer.  Your manual specification of `T` is one such way to do it, and probably the easiest.  If you want I can write this up as an answer, but unfortunately the end result will be "sorry, this isn't really possible".  Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @jcalz. I'm currently specifying `T` manually for the code that uses this, and was hoping there was a way to eliminate this redundancy (it has over 40 properties, so you might imagine my reason for asking!). If you post your first comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? It isn't exactly what you asked for. You have to initialize your creation with a `base` argument and then let the curried return infer/spoof the type.

```
// Example Usage
const creation = create({ upvotes: 0 })((set, get) => ({
  upvote: () =>
    set({
      upvotes: get().upvotes + 1,
    }),
}));
```

Here's how I hacked it together

```
export const create = <T>(base: T) => {
  let state = base
  const api = {
    _setState<U>(newState: U | T): void {
      state = { ...state, ...newState } as T & U
    },
    setState(newState: T | Partial<T>): void {
      state = { ...state, ...newState }
    },
    getState(): T {
      return state
    }
  }

  return <U>(
    act: (set: typeof api.setState, get: typeof api.getState) => U
  ) => {
    api._setState({
      ...api,
      ...act(api.setState, api.getState)
    })
    return {
      getState: api.getState,
      setState: api.setState
    } as _InternalCreateApi<T, U>
  }
}
```

```
export interface CreateApi<T> {
  getState: () => T;
  setState: (newState: T | Partial<T>) => T;
}

type _InternalCreateApi<T, U> = CreateApi<{
  [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof T
    ? T[K]
    : K extends keyof U
    ? U[K]
    : never;
}> extends CreateApi<infer V>
  ? CreateApi<V>
  : never;
```

[repo/playground](https://github.com/Cuppachino/typed-create.git)